Flow - change status via Tooling API
I am working on updating a Salesforce flow using a Python script. The script connects successfully and retrieves the flow details, but fails to update the flow with the following error message:
Failed to update flow: 400 - [{"message":"The version of the flow you're updating was active and can't be overwritten.","errorCode":"INVALID_STATUS","fields":[]}]

The flow metadata retrieved is as follows:
Flow ID: 301Dn000001lroxIAA
Status: Obsolete
MasterLabel: CQ Update Internal Comments
Flow Metadata:
{
  'actionCalls': [], 'apexPluginCalls': [], 'apiVersion': 51.0, 'assignments': [...],
  ...
  'status': 'Obsolete',
  ...
}

Despite the flow status being 'Obsolete', the update attempt results in the INVALID_STATUS error. The relevant portion of my Python script is:
import requests
from tkinter import messagebox

class SalesforceFlowUpdater:
    def __init__(self):
        # Salesforce credentials and OAuth2 parameters
        self.client_id = 'your_client_id'
        self.client_secret = 'your_client_secret'
        self.username = 'your_username'
        self.password = 'your_password'  # Salesforce password + security token
        self.login_url = 'https://your_salesforce_instance.my.salesforce.com'

    def get_access_token(self):
        # Salesforce OAuth2 endpoint
        auth_url = f'{self.login_url}/services/oauth2/token'

        # POST request for access token
        response = requests.post(auth_url, data={
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
            'username': self.username,
            'password': self.password
        })

        if response.status_code == 200:
            json_res = response.json()
            return json_res['access_token'], json_res['instance_url']
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to authenticate: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
            return None, None

    def update_flow(self, access_token, instance_url):
        # Authorization header with access token
        auth_header = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        # Salesforce REST API endpoint to query Flow metadata
        query_url = f'{instance_url}/services/data/v52.0/tooling/query/?q=' \
                    f'SELECT+Id,MasterLabel,Status,Metadata+FROM+Flow+WHERE+MasterLabel+=+\'CQ Update Internal Comments\''

        # GET request to fetch Flow metadata
        response = requests.get(query_url, headers=auth_header)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            metadata = response.json()

            if 'records' in metadata and metadata['totalSize'] > 0:
                record = metadata['records'][0]
                flow_id = record['Id']
                flow_metadata = record['Metadata']

                print("Connection successful. Retrieved flow details:")
                print(f"Flow ID: {flow_id}")
                print(f"Status: {record['Status']}")
                print(f"MasterLabel: {record['MasterLabel']}")
                print("Flow Metadata:")
                print(flow_metadata)

                # Update the necessary fields in the flow metadata
                flow_metadata['status'] = 'Active'  # Adjust status or other fields as needed

                # Salesforce REST API endpoint to update Flow metadata
                update_url = f'{instance_url}/services/data/v52.0/tooling/sobjects/Flow/{flow_id}'

                # PATCH request to update Flow metadata
                update_response = requests.patch(update_url, headers=auth_header, json={'Metadata': flow_metadata})

                if update_response.status_code == 204:
                    print("Flow updated successfully.")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to update flow: {update_response.status_code} - {update_response.text}")
            else:
                print("Connection successful but no flow found with the specified MasterLabel.")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch metadata: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

    def main(self):
        access_token, instance_url = self.get_access_token()
        if access_token and instance_url:
            self.update_flow(access_token, instance_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    updater = SalesforceFlowUpdater()
    updater.main()


Question:
How can I successfully update the flow in Salesforce without encountering the INVALID_STATUS error? Any insights on the correct procedure or additional steps required to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Hi, I'm trying to do this via metadata API

Try updating the flow definition rather than flow instance: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/402134/activating-flow-using-flow-tooling-api. See simple_salesforce for a Python client.
